# Getting IllegalArgumentException while running TestNG testcase on JDK 1.8

Tags: maven, java-8, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

After upgrading java to 1.8 version when I am trying to run test cases (`testng-6.9.4`), I am getting the following exception while running it.

I am also using 
`maven-surefire-plugin` version 2.18.1. 
com.googlecode.jmockit version 0.999.15

Exception log:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.x.SampleTest
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.979 sec - in com.x.SampleTest
st
Running com.x.OtherFileImplTest
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.271 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.x.OtherFileImplTest
testRetrieveCollectionOfViews(com.x.OtherFileImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.022 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:113)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

---

Comment: Do you have any more log? In the surefire source there's nothing indicating an exception being thrown there, but there should be a line right above the exception starting with `Configuring TestNG with: ...`

Comment: +1 This exception shouldn't there or some part of the stacktrace is missing. See https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.18.1/surefire-providers/surefire-testng/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/surefire/testng/TestNGExecutor.java#L115

Comment: Updated the exception log... @Kenney, log has something like "Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator"

Comment: You might try [forking the tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) in a separate JVM, see if that changes anything. (i.e.`<plugin><configuration><forkCount>1</forkCount><reuseForks>false</....`).

Comment: I have this configuration but still the issue.

Comment: @SanjayKr.Kushawaha Could you share your project with us?